# Where to specify drag-and-drop related meta data?

Tags: java, architecture, project-structure

The structure of our project strongly separates the three different parts:

- **core** - data classes, POJOs, sometimes aggregated with annotations (e.g. for XML/JSON serialization)
- **plugin** - plugin for a large enterprise application that is based on Swing
- **ui** - additional UI components in JavaFX, does only use the **core** data classes

Now we want to implement drag-and-drop transfers between the UI in JavaFX and the plugin in Swing. Thanks to a [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632026/custom-object-drag-and-drop-from-fx-to-swing), there are **no** more **technical issues** in the implementation.

However, I do not know **where** to put the meta information on how the data structures should be transfered through the operating system. For Swing, I need to define (or reuse) a `DataFlavor`, in JavaFX a `DataFormat` is required. Both of these classes are based on a simple string that should / must contain a MIME type, e.g. `text/plain` or `application/x-some-custom-data`. But where should this kind of information be defined?

---

1. **Idea**: Store the `DataFormat` / `DataFlavor` directly in the class that uses it, e.g. a controller:

   ```
   class MyController {

       public static final DataFormat FORMAT = new DataFormat("x-some-custom-data");

       // ...
           ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
           content.put(FORMAT, myDataObject);
       // ...
   }

   // equivalent for Swing part
   ```

   **Disadvantage**: The same information needs to be stored at different places.

---

2. **Idea**: Store the `DataFormat` / `DataFlavor` directly in the class that is transfered:

   ```
   class MyDataClass {

       public static final DataFormat FORMAT = new DataFormat("x-some-custom-data");

       public static final DataFlavor FLAVOR = ...

       // some fields / getters / setters ...

   }

   // ...
       ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
       content.put(MyDataClass.FORMAT, myDataObject);
   // ...

   // equivalent for Swing part
   ```

   **Disadvantage**: Framework-specific classes are used inside pure data classes (even if they belong to the standard Java framework).

---

3. **Idea**: Store the information at the class that is transfered, but create the framework specific classes (`DataFormat` / `DataFlavor`) somewhere else:

   ```
   @TransferAs("application/x-some-custom-data")
   class MyDataClass {

   }

   // ...
       DataFormat format = new DataFormat(myDataObject.getClass().getAnnotation(TransferAs.class).value());
   // ...

   // equivalent for Swing part
   ```

   **Disadvantage**: Requires a custom non-standard annotation that may be confusing.

---

Which idea would you consider best-practice? Is there another approach I'm totally missing right now?

Comment: Idea 3 does not require annotations. Just create a public constant and use it in a thin UI wrapper.

Comment: Of course, that would be possible and would eliminate the disadvantage. However, I would consider this kind of information meta data and this is what annotations are for. Also, this would provide me some consistent way to access the information, using a constant I would need to follow some convention, because Java does not allow some kind of contract (interface, inheritance) for static methods and fields.